# Count Part number for each date

Tags: excel

I have a long list of part numbers (jobs) that have many entries per day. I need to count how many times each part number shows up on a date. Column A is the date and Column B is the part number. If "PART X" in Column B is listed 196 times, it might cover only 3 dates and thats what I need to know, so "PART X" would equal 3. Formulas I have been trying fail. Countif, Sumif etc.  Thanks for any help

Comment: What formulas did you try? Did you use wildcards?  Sounds straightforward, so if a `CountIfs` failed, what formula were you trying? Also, what does your data look like?

Comment: You can use  DCOUNTA  or FREQUENCY for this

Comment: You could also use a Pivot Table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With data like:

[image]

Place the dates in column **D** and the parts in row **1**.

Then in **E2** enter:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(($A$1:$A$24=$D2)*($B$1:$B$24=E$1))
```

copy both across and down:

[image]

Comment: An Array Formula?  From You?  FWIW: `=COUNTIFS(A:A,$D2,B:B,E$1)`

Comment: @ScottCraner  Well.......... *Sumproduct()* is not exactly an array formula.........but *Countifs()* probably calculates faster for large datasets.

Comment: You still would not want to use full column references with it.  But it does not require Ctrl-Shift-Enter, except on occasion.

Comment: @ScottCraner  We are in complete agreement.

Comment: I think you should put in a helper column somewhere, just so I know its you and not some poser. :) sorry also just realized I forgot to upvote.

Comment: @ScottCraner  Remember that part of my username is *Student* ............I am trying to learn techniques beyond helper columns

Comment: And I am trying to realize there is more than Arrays, SUMPRODUCT and AGGREGATE.  So we could learn a little from each other.  That is why I love this site.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way is this little function:

```
=COUNTIFS(B1:B11;C1;A1:A11;D1)
```

In column B, you have all your partnumbers. In column A you have all your dates.
Then choose the job and put it in C1 and the date in D1.

Done :)

If you only need to look up one value at a time, you could easily make two "data validation lists" - one for the date and one for the parts numbers. Make these two C1 and D1 and magic will happens :)